# How to Implement "Wavesurfer. js" Sliced Senseless Loading

Tags: wavesurfer.js

wavesurfer.js How to achieve large file audio execution to a certain time, load the next piece of data in shards, and seamless splicing (how to achieve splicing)

I have currently attempted to directly increase the array and call 'load' for rendering, but the instance will be reloaded. How can I achieve seamless splicing